# Approximate stack location

Tags: c, pointers, stack-frame

Would the following work as a way to approximate the stack position of the current frame?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    char a = 'a';
    printf("The current stack is around: %p\n", &a);
    ...

}
```

I would think this would give be where `rbp` is approximately (perhaps off by an alignment or so) but wanted to see is this might work.

Comment: For security purposes, there may be a [stack guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection) whose only purpose is to make sure this doesn't work.

Comment: @user3386109: The StackGuard features in the page you link to provide methods of decreasing or detection stack corruption. They do not conceal or obscure the address of the stack frame.